# Javascript conflict causing page not to display in ie

Tags: javascript

The following page will not display in ie.
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6957663/muchWorth.html

I believe it has to do with the javasscript I implemented but I'm not sure.

Is there some file encoding I am missing?

I am on ubuntu linux in gedit.

Comment: Run it through a validator - http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6957663/muchWorth.html&charset=(detect+automatically)&doctype=Inline&group=0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `<title>` tag is not closed properly in the header. You used `</h1>`.

While we're looking at the code, you may also want to use

- `<style type='text/css'>`
- `<script type='text/javascript'>`

to clarify those elements of the HTML.

// EDIT

Incidentally, to find this diagnosis quickly, I

- Commented out all Javascript, didn't work
- Commented out all CSS, didn't work
- Started at the top looking for strange-ness, and there it was.

I'd recommend doing that next time this comes up.  :)

Comment: Thank you so much!! This was driving me crazy.  I am just waiting for the timer to let me accept.